# How to go to next difference when comparing documents in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, file-compare

I'm comparing two very similar documents using `review, compare, compare`. Word shows me both but I do not see how to jump to each differences.

How can I jump to next difference?

I'm using Word 2016

Comment: There's probably a function and corresponding key mapping in Word, but I don't know it.  You might be interested in WinMerge, assuming you're using Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Word marks the differences between documents as tracked changes. So you can navigate among them the same way that you navigate among tracked changes – e.g., by using the **Previous** and **Next** buttons in the **Changes** group on the **Review** tab. (Make sure that **All Markup** is selected in the **Display for Review** field in the **Tracking** group.)

[image: Previous and Next buttons in the Changes group on the Review tab]

Alternatively (and again, just as for tracked changes), you can click **Reviewing Pane** in the **Tracking** group to open a pane that shows a list of the differences and lets you jump to individual differences by clicking them.

Comment: That's not an anwser to the question: navigating between differences of two documents. The answer moves between changen inside one of the documents.

Comment: `Next` was ghosted for me, but Reviewing Pane worked!